# How to say char1 = f and char2 = t?

Tags: java, char

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class DatentypChar {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException { 

        char c1 = (char) System.in.read(); 
        char c2 = (char) System.in.read(); 

        c1 = 'f' || 't'; // I would like to say c1 is f or t and c2 is t or f. 
        c2 = 't' || 'f';

        if(c1 == 'f' && c2 == 'f');{
            System.out.println(0); 

        }

        if(c1 == 'f' && c2 == 't');{
            System.out.println(1);
        }

        if(c1 == 't' && c2 == 'f');{
            System.out.println(2);
        }

        if(c1 == 't' && c2 == 't');{
            System.out.println(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Hi guys 
That is how it looks currently. How can i fix that? 
I would like to say `c1` is `f` or `t` and `c2` is `f` or `t`.

TASK:

Write a program to the two characters (data type char) over the
Standard input. The two characters represent Boolean
Values. Character 'f' for false and character 't' for true. Depending on this input an int value with hint text is displayed on the standard output. The
Dependence is shown in the following table:

```
1st character 2nd character Output value
false         false         0
false         true          1
true          false         2
true          true          3
```

If no valid combination is entered, then a meaningful
Error message generated.

Comment: when should be c1 f and when should be it t.?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you trying to verify the user input? In that case, just take care of that in your `if` statements.

Comment: If i enter it via keyboard. It should be possible to enter just f or t. F for False and T for True.

Comment: You can't prevent the user to enter anything else. But you can check, using an if statement, whether the user has entered what you expect or not, and print an error message in that case.

Comment: Your question is unclear (comments don't belong to question description). Use [edit] option to clarify what you want to achieve in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done.  
What you can do though is use boolean variables to check the validity of input:

```
boolean first = (c1 == 'f') || (c1 == 't');
boolean second = (c2 == 'f') || (c2 == 't');

if (first && second) {
    if (c1 == 'f' && c2 == 'f')
        System.out.println("Both are false: " + 0);
    else if (c1 == 'f' && c2 == 't')
        System.out.println("First is false and second is true: " + 1);
    else if (c1 == 't' && c2 == 'f')
        System.out.println("First is true and second is false: " + 2);
    else if (c1 == 't' && c2 == 't')
        System.out.println("Both are true: " + 3);
} else {
        System.out.println("No valid data entered");
}
```

Here `first` and `second` are `boolean` variables that will be `true` only if input was valid.  
So if they are both `true` you can print the desired output.  
The above code can be more simplified to this:

```
boolean first = (c1 == 'f') || (c1 == 't');
boolean second = (c2 == 'f') || (c2 == 't');

if (first && second) {
    if (c1 == 'f' && c2 == 'f')
        System.out.println("Both are false: " + 0);
    else if (c1 == 'f')
        System.out.println("First is false and second is true: " + 1);
    else if (c2 == 'f')
        System.out.println("First is true and second is false: " + 2);
    else
        System.out.println("Both are true: " + 3);
} else {
        System.out.println("No valid data entered");
}
```

**Also** **don't** do this:

```
if(c1 == 'f' && c2 == 't');
```

the semicolon at the end of the `if` statement is wrong

Comment: That is how the Task should be:
Write a program to the two characters (data type char) over the
Standard input. The two characters represent Boolean
Values. Character 'f' for false and character 't' for true. Depending on this input
an int value with hint text is displayed on the standard output. The
Dependence is shown in the following table:
 
1st character 2nd character Output value
false false 0
false true 1
true false 2
true true 3
 
If no valid combination is entered, then a meaningful
Error message generated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to ask, how to validate that the user is entering either 't' or 'f'.

In that case, you can use a while loop that you exit once the user has entered the correct values, like so:

```
char c1;
char c2;
boolean correctInput = false;
while (!correctInput) {
    System.out.println("Enter t or f");
    c1 = (char) System.in.read(); 
    c2 = (char) System.in.read(); 
    if ((c1 == 't' || c1 == 'f') && (c2 == 't' || c2 == 'f')) {
        correctInput = true;
    }
}
//Rest of your code...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string combStr =  String.Join("", 
    Console.ReadKey().KeyChar, 
    Console.ReadKey().KeyChar 
    );

int ?ansOut = null;

if (combStr.Replace("f", "").Replace("t", "").Length < combStr.Length)
{                
    if (combStr == "ff")
        ansOut = 0;
    if (combStr == "ft")
        ansOut = 1;
    if (combStr == "tf")
        ansOut = 2;
    if (combStr == "tt")
        ansOut = 3;

    Console.WriteLine(ansOut);                
}
```